# Question on how to pass argument to Twilio Message Create

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I have another script that will be passing phone numbers to my "Twilio SMS App". But, when I pass the phone number argument to client.message.create function it says the phone number is not a valid phone number. Which, if I type it out in the message.create it works just fine. My guess is I have to format it correctly, But I can't get it right. This is what I have so far. Looking for some guidance. Let me know if you need any more info or if I didn't explain well enough.

-Thanks for the help :)

```
def send():

    twilio_number = '+15555555555'
    message_body = 'Hello, Free World!!'
    number = '+25555555555'
    message = client.messages.create(
        to=number,
        from_=twilio_number,
        body=message_body,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

All phone numbers should be in proper E.164 format, a defined below, otherwise nothing looks off. Are you sure the destination is capable of receiving an SMS (you do mention manually it works, so strange).

[Formatting International Phone Numbers](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183008-Formatting-International-Phone-Numbers)

Comment: Yes, I changed out the my number for that random one. But yes it my personal phone. I did find out that If I remove the 3rd , after body=message_body it worked. But thanks for the help